# My Domain Emails using Google Apps Business are getting sent to spam by the gmail recipient

Tags: email, gmail, google-apps, spam, spf

I just found out my domain's emails have been going to the spam folder of gmail recipients. I did some research and I put the following in my DNS records for my domain name:

```
TXT - "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

I'm not sure if I have to put anything before the spf like my server's IP address or `a` or `mx` in some configurations I see. I mainly use my google apps domain email by using my plain gmail account and set "Send As" to send from the domain specific emails.

Is there something else I am missing or overlooking that I need to do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only using google apps to send emails then that's the correct SPF record.

If you want to be sure, the best thing you can do is send an email to

```
mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com
check-auth@verifier.port25.com
```

They are know as reflectors and will auto-respond with your configuration, letting you know if you have your SPF set up correctly.

If you're unsure of what you need just use an [SPF Wizard](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/spfwizard/), but I think based on your description you're 100% fine. The MX and A just tells the receiving mail server that if the mail comes from you MX or A of your domain, then it's a good email, but you're sending from google, so you wouldn't need it.

Also with GMAIL in-boxing takes time and SPF isn't the magic cure, but it helps.

Comment: The definitive SPF checker is [Scott Kitterman's](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html).